# Find missing value from API array using parsed SQL values

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am fairly new to SQL and APIs so if the question is trivial I am sorry about that ...

I just learned to SELECT query user ID's in my SQL database which I map and parse to use as parameters in a GET call using searchParam.

All values in the database is 100% correct, but the API sometimes does not return certain arrays and I want to know which one is missing.

My SQL database parsed values return something like this `["10941","21707229","30827766","30918070","30924695","116669947"]`

The website's API GET data array result looks something like this

```
[
{
    id: '10941',
    name: 'Susan Brown',
},
{
    id: '21707229',
    name: 'Bob White',
},
{
    id: '30827766',
    name: 'Michel Blue',
},
{
    id: '30918070',
    name: 'Marvin Grey',
},
{
    id: '30924695',
    name: 'Susan Red',
}
]
```

What I am looking to do is return `116669947` value which is missing from my API GET call.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `filter` function on the array!

```js
const database = ["10941","21707229","30827766","30918070","30924695","116669947"]

const api = [
{
    id: '10941',
    name: 'Susan Brown',
},
{
    id: '21707229',
    name: 'Bob White',
},
{
    id: '30827766',
    name: 'Michel Blue',
},
{
    id: '30918070',
    name: 'Marvin Grey',
},
{
    id: '30924695',
    name: 'Susan Red',
}
]

// Filter the database array, including only IDs that aren't found in the object
const notInAPI = database.filter(x => !api.find(y => x == y.id));
console.log(notInAPI);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works exactly as intended, I will use this data elsewhere so I will dig more into the filtre and find methods!